# series of cloudkit callbacks - when to popover to previous controller

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I have series of sequential cloud kit calls to fetch records each based on previous fetch. Any one of these fetches may fail and then I have to popover to previous controller. Since there are so many places the fetches can fail, I have to embed popViewController to previous controller in many locations. Can I avoid this and call popover only once if it is possible?

```
 func iCloudSaveMeterHubPrivateDbCz() {

    self.clOps.iCloudFetchRecord(recordName: locId, databaseScope: CKDatabaseScope.private, customZone: true, completion: { (locationRecord, error) in
       guard error == nil else {
             self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
            return
        }
        self.iCloudFetchMeter(withLocationCKRecord: locationRecord!) { records, error in
            if (error != nil ) {
                if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
                    self.aErrorHandler.handleCkError(ckerror: ckerror)
                }
                 self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            if let _ = records?.first {
                      self.clOps.iCloudFetchRecord(recordName: contactId, databaseScope: CKDatabaseScope.private, customZone: true, completion: { (contactRecord, error) in
                    if let ckerror = error as? CKError {
                        self.aErrorHandler.handleCkError(ckerror: ckerror)
                         self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let record = contactRecord {
                            record.setObject("true" as NSString, forKey:"assignedEEP")
                        }
                    }
                }
                 self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
        }

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I get into nested callbacks like this, I try to consolidate handling a response to a single point in the code. The popular motto of coders helps in this case: *"don't repeat yourself"*

Here's a suggestion for consolidating error handling and popping to a single place by making your main function have a closure:

```
func iCloudSaveMeter(finished: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ error: CKError?) -> Void){

  self.clOps.iCloudFetchRecord(recordName: locId, databaseScope: CKDatabaseScope.private, customZone: true, completion: { (locationRecord, error) in
    if error != nil {
      //:::
      finished(false, error)
    }
    self.iCloudFetchMeter(withLocationCKRecord: locationRecord!) { records, error in
      if error != nil {
        //:::
        finished(false, error)
      }
      if let _ = records?.first {
        self.clOps.iCloudFetchRecord(recordName: contactId, databaseScope: CKDatabaseScope.private, customZone: true, completion: { contactRecord, error in
          //:::
          finished(false, error)

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let record = contactRecord {
              record.setObject("true" as NSString, forKey:"assignedEEP")
            }
          }
        }
      }

      //:::
      finished(true, nil)
    }
  })
}

//----
//Call it like this
iCloudSaveMeter(){ success, error in 
  //Pop
  if !success{ 
    self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
  }

  //Hande error
  if let error = error{
    self.aErrorHandler.handleCkError(ckerror: error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like charm!